# Get info about what resource is blocking task in FreeRTOS

Tags: embedded, mutex, semaphore, blocking, freertos

I have a FreeRTOS (v9.0 in case it matters) based embedded product. This product has multiple tasks, which interact with each other using multiple semaphores, mutexes, queues, and other task blocking resources. Unfortunately, I have a seldom occurring bug which causes one tasks to permanently block on some resource (perhaps a deadly embrace?).

My efforts to trap it so far have been fruitless. However, I can attach a debugger to the running target after the problem happens, and pause the processor. Since I have each tasks's handle as a global variable, I was hoping to extract some useful information about which resource the task is blocked by. However, a handle is nothing but a pointer, and I can't figure out how to get useful information from that.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can find out which task blocking resource is holding off the task?

**UPDATE:** It seems to me that, since I know the task which is getting stuck, I should be able to look at its stack and extract some useful information about that. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get access to the current stack pointer, nor how deep into the stack I'd have to go to make sense of what's on there.

Comment: To clarify, you know which task is the culprit, just not which task resource?

Comment: Can you instrument the potentially-blocking calls in the task that gets blocked to establish which line in the task source code is being blocked?

Comment: I'd use some non-blocking toggling of LEDs and/or GPIOs (given you have an embedded system) mapped to accesses of each task/task resource. That should pretty quickly identify the offending items by the lack of a signal.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @Ed King, you are correct, I know which task is blocked, but not why.

Comment: @barney, instrumenting the blocking calls is a rather large undertaking because there are many (upwards of 100?) possible resources on which I could be blocking and, given the irregularity of this problem, I'm afraid that simply instrumenting code around those blocking calls would change the behavior.

Comment: The task handle is simply a pointer to the task TCB. Cast it to TCB_t * and you will be able to examine it's contents (which will give you it's stack pointer etc)

Comment: Rather than instrumenting all the possible calls, they probably group into related ones - instrument some carefully selected points will probably help you focus in on just one area. Of course anything you do could change the behaviour, but doing nothing doesn't seem likely to actually solve your problem.